# Crystal Report: Running Total: Evaluate on formula

Tags: crystal-reports, field

I have a crystal report where I am trying to show running totals of amounts based on certain criteria.
My data looks like this:

```
expect_real_money    amount   pay_type
Y                    500.00   CASH
Y                     20.00   CHECK
N                    -20.00   ADJ
Y                    300.00   VISA
Y                    200.00   M/C
Y                    100.00   VISA
```

I created a running total with formula as:

```
({spcscdailyrevrpt.expect_real_money} = 'Y') AND
    ( 
        (instr({spcscdailyrevrpt.pay_type}, 'CASH', 1) = 0) AND // NOT found
        (instr({spcscdailyrevrpt.pay_type}, 'CHECK', 1) = 0)  // NOT found     
    )
```

According to the values, the running total(sum) should show as 580. But, its showing 600. My question is: does crystal report take absolute value of a number when calculating running totals?

Any help is appreciated.
NH

Comment: please write the whole formula , not just a part of it

Comment: that is the whole formula that evaluates to a boolean

Comment: in the evaluate section, I use this formula to filter out records.

Comment: it looks to me that based on your formula and the test data that 600 is what should be returned.. ({spcscdailyrevrpt.expect_real_money} = 'Y') discounts line 3 ..  (instr({spcscdailyrevrpt.pay_type}, 'CASH', 1) = 0) AND  discounts line 1 ... (instr({spcscdailyrevrpt.pay_type}, 'CHECK', 1) = 0)  // NOT found  discounts line 2 leaving 300+200+100 = 600